# How to enable VS Code auto-imports with Yarn 2.0's link: protocol and Typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

I am using Yarn 2 with PnP enabled and Typescript. In my dependencies, I have `"app": "link:./"` for absolute imports as described [here](https://yarnpkg.com/features/protocols/#why-is-the-link-protocol-recommended-over-aliases-for-path-mapping), no paths or baseUrl in my tsconfig. What I want is auto-import of files to be absolute too and not relative. I used to have baseUrl and it worked fine.